# How to access data in sql request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm runing a sql request in a model to get some data in relation.

I got a array called `newScoring` with `["_646_maturity", "_660_maturity", "_651_maturity", "_652_maturity", "_641_maturity"]`

```
newScoring.each do |e|
      numero = e.from(1).to(-10) // remove text to get only number : 646

      sql = "SELECT * FROM pratiques WHERE numero LIKE '%"+numero+"%'" // sql request to get a pratique with numero equal to my previous number

      records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

      Rails.logger.debug "SQL : "+records_array
end
```

When I log `records_array.inspect`, I got

`[{"id"=>1, "numero"=>646, "titre"=>"Acquérir en priorité des équipements reconditionnés", "ponderation"=>3, "texte_kpi"=>"% du parc reconditionné", "section"=>"achats-responsables", "created_at"=>"2019-06-03 14:10:14.228234", "updated_at"=>"2019-06-03 14:10:14.228234"}]`

I want to access to `ponderation` value but I didn't find any docs related. I tried differents things but got errors messages with string conversion.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In which model are you? Do you have any model for this table `pratiques` something like `Pratique`?

Comment: Where is the array `newScoring` comming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `records_array` is an Array of Hashes you need to first select the row (Hash) you want and then access the desired column:

```rb
records_array.first['ponderation'] # or records_array[0]['ponderation']
=> 3
```

Btw, if you are on Rails, why don't you generate a model for `practiques` and use ActiveRecord?

Comment: I got this error : `no implicit conversion of Integer into String` .. 

Quite new on Rails, and it seem the best way to access to the database, but yes, true

Comment: Probably one of the IDs does not exist, resulting in an empty query! Just out of curiosity, why are you looping through the array like this? This is resulting in N+1 queries. In other words, you get as many queries as array items. Not really good for performance.